# Modulo time to get seconds, minutes, hours etc

Tags: objective-c, math, time, modulo

Im trying to build a countdown, which has four sections:

to be displayed like this:

0 0 : 0 0

tenminutes minutes : tenseconds seconds

Ive got the _secs working below, the _tensecs goes up to 9 which is no good.

```
int seconds;
int _secs;
int _tensecs;
int _mins;
int _tenmins;

-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    seconds++; 

    _secs = seconds % 10;
    _tensecs = (seconds / 10) % 10;  // wrong
    _mins = seconds // ??
    _m_tenminsins = seconds // ??
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this question is barely related with Objective-C. The only Objective-C thing I can see is the method definition which is not relevant to the countdown question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _secs = seconds % 10;
 _tensecs = (seconds / 10) % 6;
 _mins = (seconds / 60) % 10;
 _tenmins = (seconds / 600) % 6;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if `% 10` gives you values that go up to `9`, what do you think you need to modulo by to get values that go up to `5`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Objective-C, but this should do what you want:

```
int seconds;
int _secs;
int _tensecs;
int _mins;
int _tenmins;

-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    seconds--; 

    _secs = seconds % 60;
    _tensecs = _secs / 10;
    _secs = _secs % 10;

    _mins = seconds / 60;
    _tenmins = _mins / 10;
    _mins = _mins % 10;
}
```

This assumes `seconds` is positive and you're counting down.  If you really want it negative and counting up, as you seem to be indicating, then change to:

```
    seconds++;

    _secs = abs(seconds) % 60;

...

    _mins = abs(seconds) / 60;

...
```